# Using batch size as variable in model creation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I face the following issue about `tf.reshape`.

Code:

```
class ReshapeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ReshapeLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    assert len(x.shape) == 3
    b, n, d = x.shape
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, (1, n, b*d))
    return x

x = tf.random.normal((20, 10, 5))
ReshapeLayer()(x).shape
```

> TensorShape([1, 10, 100])

However:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, 5))
output = ReshapeLayer()(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(input=inputs, output=output)
```

```
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape_layer_3" (type ReshapeLayer).

in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-5-13bfec4ca4b4>", line 9, in call  *
        x = tf.reshape(x, (1, n, b*d))

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'


Call arguments received by layer "reshape_layer_3" (type ReshapeLayer):
  • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 10, 5), dtype=float32)
```

I am aware that batch size during model creation is `None`. I tried `tf.shape(x)` to treat the dimensions as variable, but it didn't work. How can I get around that exception?

-------------- Addition -------------------

Finally, I want to be able to do something like this after changing the layer definition as suggested.

```
class ReshapeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ReshapeLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    assert len(x.shape) == 3
    n = tf.shape(x)[1]  # x.shape[1] should work as well
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, (1, n, -1))
    return x

x = tf.random.normal((20, 10, 5))
ReshapeLayer()(x).shape
```

Now, I want to use the result of the reshape layer as input to another, possibly custom, layer. Here in the example I took a Dense layer.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, 5))
x = ReshapeLayer()(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (1, 10, None)
```

How can I handle this error?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
class ReshapeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ReshapeLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    assert len(x.shape) == 3
    shape = tf.shape(x)
    b, n, d = shape[0], shape[1], shape[2]
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, (1, n, b*d))
    return x

x = tf.random.normal((20, 10, 5))
ReshapeLayer()(x).shape
```

You just have to access the `tf.shape` result a bit differently as it returns a tensor.

Note that `model = tf.keras.Model(input=inputs, output=output)` crashes, you need to use `model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)` (the kwargs are plural).

Finally, you can also do this

```
class ReshapeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ReshapeLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    assert len(x.shape) == 3
    n = tf.shape(x)[1]  # x.shape[1] should work as well
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, (1, n, -1))
    return x

x = tf.random.normal((20, 10, 5))
ReshapeLayer()(x).shape
```

You can use `-1` in reshape calls to basically tell Tensorflow "figure it out yourself".

Comment: Thanks! That indeed does the trick with the prulal in the argument names. I added an Addition section to my question, maybe you can have a look at it? @xdurch0

Comment: Ok, in that case you cannot use the variant with `-1` so you should choose the first option.

Comment: The first option doesnt work, same error as above. It's because the batch dimension is  into the last dimension and during model init it's `None`.